# Asp.net web forms control in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to inject an asp.net classic web control to my asp.net mvc application. This control doesn't use view state or post back so it works fine.

But I can't plug a real-time provided value in its attribute. This code

```
<my:Control runat="server" Tag="<%: Model.ID %>" />
```

ends up with the tag value just set explicitly to "<%: Model.ID %>".
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: out of curiosity, what type of'classic' asp.net web control are you trying to use?

Comment: It it a third-party control for file uploading I was using in asp.net webforms before switching to mvc. It just renders an appropriate html markup for a silverlight app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the syntax is as follows:

```
<my:Control runat="server" Tag="<%# Model.ID %>" />
```

The other gotcha is you must call .DataBind() on the Control at some point after the Control has been initialized. This probably means taping into the Page_Load or OnInit events of the Page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Label1.DataBind();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# DateTime.Now %>" />
</asp:Content>
```

Or, if you have access to the  source, you could add a call to .DataBind() somewhere before the final Render. You would have to experiment with that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this could only work in classic asp.net app (asp.net web forms), not in asp.net mvc

Comment: The code above works just fine in an ASP.NET MVC app. To the best of my knowledge, there is no other way to call .DataBind(), unless you have access to the controls source code where you can manually add the call to .DataBind().

Comment: Adding OnInit handler will work in asp.net webforms, but I beleive not in mvc. And I think yes, it would be the best solution to add the call to DataBind() somewhere in the control's source, but unfortunalty I don't have access to it

Comment: You can add/call the OnInit page handler if using the default ASP.MVC View engine. I haven't tested other View engines (like Razor), although I suspect it's no different, but I could be wrong about that one.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to override OnInit function? I'm using the default asp.net mvc view engine

Comment: Wow, that is something I missed during exploring asp.net mvc caps. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like the only way to do this is injecting code the control renders to the page directly. In my case the control renders a silverlight object with some javascript so I put it at the page as is.